# In ModelAdmin, how do I get the object's previous values when overriding `save_model()`

Tags: django, python-3.x

When overriding `ModelAdmin.save_model()`, I want to be able to run some calculations between the object's new values vs its old ones. Is there any way that I can get the "old object" with all its previous data before the change?

For example, if I have an `Object` with `obj.name` = "foo" that I update via the Django admin app to now be `obj.name` = "bar", upon saving the following code should print out accordingly:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
          old_object = self.get_old_object()
          print(old_object.name)  # Should print out "foo"
          print(obj.name)         # Should print out "bar"
```

Comment: you should consider doing it with signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#pre-save this way it will work for all other views and not just in admin

Comment: I can't use signals because I need to be able to manually call these calculations and not have them go off every time save is called. There's also the issue of `old_object` still not being accessible from pre-save

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you could get the object via a database lookup like this

```
old_object = self.model.objects.get(id=obj.id)
```

If you need to deal with the case where it doesn't exists you can do

```
try:
    old_object = self.model.objects.get(id=obj.id)
except self.model.DoesNotExist:
    ...
```

Also `self.model` is just set to the your model class in the ModelAdmin so you could replace that with your model class

Comment: Thanks HWite4! The possibility that the old data would still be alive in the db completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 4):

@hwhite4 answer does what is expected. However, if you want to avoid that database lookup, you can do instead:

```
old_object = form.initial['name']
```

Where `name` is the name of the field.